# Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

i use from wso2 esb to add proxy service. i hvae an error when i try to call this web service. this is my proxy service :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="citynetserviceMain"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
 <target>
  <inSequence>
     <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING"
               value="true"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://citynetservice..../CityBank.svc?wsdl"
                    format="soap12"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
</target>
<publishWSDL uri="http://citynetservice..../CityBank.svc?wsdl"/>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

when i try to call this proxy service it throw an exception :

```
<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found</TryitProxyError>
```

Comment: show the your proxy endpoint do you use in the try it. and you can use better soapui for testing.

Comment: with soapui it work fine. but in tryit it throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are facing the same issue as mine, but I've had the same problem when an other server (tomcat) was listening on port 8280.

The ESB start without any problem but you can find an error in esb logs that say that port is already in use

You can access ESB console on port 9443 and use "try this service", but in my case, tomcat were sending back a 404.

Hope it can help.

Comment: tanx . my problem solved i use wcf service so i changed endpoint to "http://citynetservice..../CityBank.svc/soap" and use soap 1.1.